# PowerBI-visuals-tools d3 import

Tags: typescript, d3.js, powerbi

I created a new project using the visual tools of PowerBI (https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-tools) and then I manually installed d3 (@^3.5.5) and its type definitions (@types/d3@^3.5.5). What's been puzzling me is inside `visual.ts` of the `src` folder, I can use d3 without any imports, is there anybody who can explain why?

```
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {
    "use strict";
    export class Visuall implements IVisual {
        private target: HTMLElement;
        private updateCount: number;
        private settings: VisualSettings;

        constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
            console.log('Visual constructor', options);
            this.target = options.element;
            this.updateCount = 0;
        }

        public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
            this.settings = Visual.parseSettings(options && options.dataViews && options.dataViews[0]);
            console.log('Visual update', options);
            this.target.innerHTML = `<p>Update count: <em>${(this.updateCount++)}</em></p>`;
            console.log(d3); // no error whatsoever
        }


        private static parseSettings(dataView: DataView): VisualSettings {
            return VisualSettings.parse(dataView) as VisualSettings;
        }

        /**
         * This function gets called for each of the objects defined in the capabilities files and allows you to select which of the
         * objects and properties you want to expose to the users in the property pane.
         *
         */
        public enumerateObjectInstances(options: EnumerateVisualObjectInstancesOptions): VisualObjectInstance[] | VisualObjectInstanceEnumerationObject {
            return VisualSettings.enumerateObjectInstances(this.settings || VisualSettings.getDefault(), options);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly not speaking as any sort of authority on the issue, but it appears that what the Power BI Visuals API team has done is shifted the responsibility for linking files together to the build process. If you look in the pbiviz.json file there is a property for "externalJS" which is supposed to hold any js references you will be using. Since they are being referenced there, I believe it is meant to preclude the need for you to do it inside of your typescript files.